# Recursion with WTForms and Jinja

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to build a screen with Flask, WTForms, and Jinja. It will show a recursive structure where each level can be a form **OR** a group of forms. For purposes of explanation, assume the form I'm trying to show is called *ChildForm*. I am hoping to represent this kind of structure...

> [ChildForm, ChildForm, [ChildForm, ChildForm], ChildForm]

although it might go more levels deep.

A simplified version of my forms looks like the following (right now although I've been through a lot of possibilities trying to figure this out)...

```
class ChildForm(FlaskForm):
    table = SelectField(label='Table Column')
    comparator = StringField(label='Equals', default='=')
    golden_set = SelectField(label='Golden Set Column')
    btn_add_rule = SubmitField(label='Add Rule')
    btn_delete_rule = SubmitField(label='Delete Rule')

class ParentForm(FlaskForm):
    tbl_name = HiddenField(label='Table Name')
    rules = []
    btn_save = SubmitField(label='Save')
    btn_cancel = SubmitField(label='Cancel')
```

So, ParentForm.rules is currently a Python list. I was hoping to fill that with instances of ChildForm and/or lists containing multiple instances of ChildForm. The problem with this structure is that Jinja2 skips over *rules* as it iterates over the fields in ParentForm.

I have tried changing *rules* to be of type FieldList containing instances ChildForm, adding new instances with WTForms .append_entry method, but, this doesn't seem to allow me to create sublists of rules.

Any ideas on how I might make this sometimes recursive structure? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure here, but I feel like these Field Enclosures will get you a lot closer to what you're trying to do: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#field-enclosures

The `FieldList` is probably going to be important too.

I'm thinking that you have to make the actual data entry form be a base class, and then the parent class can both inherit it and also have a field list of enclosures that reference it.

```
class ChildForm(FlaskForm):
    table = SelectField(label='Table Column')
    comparator = StringField(label='Equals', default='=')
    golden_set = SelectField(label='Golden Set Column')
    btn_add_rule = SubmitField(label='Add Rule')
    btn_delete_rule = SubmitField(label='Delete Rule')

class ParentForm(ChildForm):
    tbl_name = HiddenField(label='Table Name')
    rules = FieldList(FormField(ChildForm)))
    btn_save = SubmitField(label='Save')
    btn_cancel = SubmitField(label='Cancel')
```

That's a really rough sketch of what I'm thinking.  I have no idea if it'll work.  I haven't tried to run it.

Comment: Thanks for giving this some thought, Mike. I'm not sure it will work for me, though, as I don't see a way to put sub lists into FieldList. I think I may get what I need through WTForms-JSON as that seems to support recursive structures. If I can get it to work, I'll post the answer here. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying.  Bummer.  Good luck!